# Xamarin Android Support Design Library Not Available

Tags: android, xml, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have added the Xamarin Android Support Design Library (and all of its dependencies) using NuGet in Visual Studio, but when I go to use a component in my AXML code it says it is an invalid child element.  From all the documentation and examples I could find, it doesn't seem like anything extra needs to be done other than adding the package via NuGet.  I can see all of the libraries in the References folder in the Solution Explorer.

I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly simple, but I cannot find what is wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
   xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   p1:orientation="vertical"
   p1:layout_width="match_parent"
   p1:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
        p1:src="@drawable/boxlogo"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/boxLogo" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       p1:layout_width="match_parent"
       p1:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <EditText
           p1:layout_width="match_parent"
           p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
           p1:id="@+id/sku"
           p1:hint="@string/sku" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
...
</LinearLayout>
```

I get the error on the tag with `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

I am able to access the libraries in my C# code.

Comment: What error? May be you should use [TextInputEditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html) instead of EditText?

Comment: "The element 'LinearLayout' has invalid child element 'android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout'" is the error I get and I assume that's the same error Alex gets. The Xamarin Blog gives the example with 'EditText' (https://blog.xamarin.com/add-beautiful-material-design-with-the-android-support-design-library/) but even when using 'android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText' it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs for `TextInputLayout`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html

It says:

> The TextInputEditText class is provided to be used as a child of this layout. Using TextInputEditText allows TextInputLayout greater control over the visual aspects of any text input. An example usage is as so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/form_username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

So it seems you need to use an `EditText` from the support library, e.g. `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`

Comment: Alex didn't write the exact error message but from the description I think he gets the same that I get: "The element 'LinearLayout' has invalid child element 'android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout'". I'm using TextInputEditText and it doesn't make a difference.